# Steering wheel angle control

Tags: control, matlab, autonomous-car, robot-model

I am working on an autonomous vehicle's control, specifically the steering angle control.

Knowing that I used kinematic bicycle model, my questions are:

- How do I choose the actuator for my steering wheel angle?
- Why did the article (below) use a stepper motor?
- According to what do we choose an actuator to build a control system for steering angle control?
  [image: article]

Answer (score 2):

> How do I choose the actuator for my steering wheel angle?

- Assuming this actuator will be directly driving the steering angle controller which take rotary inputs, you'll need a - Rotary actuator.
- Velocity, Acceleration - how fast you want the actuator to turn, and how quickly would you like it to reach your desired velocity
- Next is torque - this is the sum of static torque (i.e. torque required to rotate with 0 angular acceleration), dynamic torque (Torque required to accelerate - more on that: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/in-in-class11th-physics/in-in-system-of-particles-and-rotational-motion/in-in-rotational-inertia-and-angular-second-law/a/rotational-inertia-ap1) and some buffer to account for variations in the system.
- Voltage - Match your system voltage - since motors draw significant power, sticking with battery voltage is ideal, rather than losing power in stepping up/down. (a 220V motor is no good on a setup where max 12V is available)

> Why did the article (below) use a stepper motor?

Likely, they had a stepper motor and controller handy, but only the author can say for sure.

Folks also like to use stepper motors as they are slightly easier to control. Other actuators are suitable as well in a closed loop setup (eg. BLDC, Brushed motors). BLDC motors are almost always better for such applications as they provide a high torque at low speeds and can accelerate rapidly.

> According to what do we choose an actuator to build a control system for steering angle control?

The above 2 should take you close to the finish line.